# Getting a broken image icon when printing a JEditorPane

Tags: java, applet, jeditorpane

I have a small applet that is meant to print the html from a given url to form a small receipt.  It's all text except for an image at the end (barcode).  In my initial tests everything was working when the sample barcode was located in the same directory as the jar file that has my applet's code.

The problem now is that for each url I want to print, the image at the bottom will be unique and generated on the fly (pretty much an encoding of the id).

Something like this:

```
<img src="/asp/barcode.asp?id=2147419365" />
```

When I view the html page itself for the generated receipt it all shows up fine, but when I print I lose the image (a broken image icon appears).  I have tried specifying a full path in the image source, but it didn't change anything.  The strange part is that if I run it off my hard drive with the with all files in the same folder and that dynamic barcode it prints correctly.  Once I put it on my localhost it loses the barcode.  This is my print method in the applet:

```
public void printDocument(final String url) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction<Object>()
                {
        @Override
        public Object run()
        {
            try
            {
                new ParserDelegator();
                JEditorPane jEditorPane = new JEditorPane();
                jEditorPane.setPage(url);
                JeditorRendererer docRenderer = new JeditorRendererer();
                docRenderer.print(jEditorPane);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    });
}
```

Currently, when deployed, the jar file, the receipt generator, and the barcode generator are all in different locations.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="/asp/barcode.asp?id=2147419365" />
```

You most likely need to use an URL that is relative to the HTML.  e.g.

```
<img src="../asp/barcode.asp?id=2147419365" />
```